# Angular 4: Mock ElementRef

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to figure out how to mock an `ElementRef` that is injected into a component. My component is as follows:

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _appService: AppService) {
    console.log(this._elementRef);
    console.log(this._appService);
  }
}
```

and my test spec as follows:

**app.component.spec.ts:**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Injectable()
export class MockElementRef {
  nativeElement: {}  
}

@Injectable()
export class MockAppService {

}

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: ElementRef, useClass: MockElementRef},
        {provide: AppService, useClass: MockAppService}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  ...
});
```

When the tests are ran, the output from the `console.log`'s in constructor of `app.component.ts` is:

[image: console output]

As you can see, it's injecting the `MockAppService` but not the `MockElementRef` (even though they are both mocked in the same way).

This [SO post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623065/angular2-inject-elementref-in-unit-test) to set it up as you would any other mock, however I've noticed that this is for Angular 2 - so am wondering if things have changed in Angular 4?

A Plunker with the above code and Jasmine tests can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gTjUg396RI2SmSvGWjKd?p=preview). Run the Plunker then click the "Run Unit Tests" link in order to start the unit tests. The console output can be observed in developer tools/Firebug.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The short answer - *it's by design* :)

Let's dive into the longer answer step by step and try to figure out - what's going on under the hood when we configure a Testing Module via `TestBed`.

**Step 1**

According to the source code of [test_bed.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts):

```
configureTestingModule(moduleDef: TestModuleMetadata): void {
  if (moduleDef.providers) {
    this._providers.push(...moduleDef.providers);
  }
  if (moduleDef.declarations) {
    this._declarations.push(...moduleDef.declarations);
  }
  // ...
}
```

As we can see - `configureTestingModule` method simply pushes the provided instances into the `this._providers` array. And then we can say: hey, `TestBed`, give me this provider `ElementRef`:

```
  // ...
  let elRef: ElementRef;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // ...
      providers: [{provide: ElementRef, useValue: new MockElementRef()}]
    });

    // ...
    elRef = TestBed.get(ElementRef);
  });

  it('test', () => {
    console.log(elRef);
  });
```

In the console we'll see:

[image]

*First console was logged from component constructor and the second one - from the test.* 
*So, it seems like we're dealing with two different instances of `ElementRef`*. Let's move on.

**Step 2**

Let's take a look at another example and say we have a component which injects `ElementRef` and some other custom service `AppService` which we created before:

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _appService: AppService) {
    console.log(this._elementRef);
    console.log(this._appService);
  }
}
```

When we test this component - we must provide `AppService` (the service itself or its mock), **BUT**, if we don't provide `ElementRef` to `TestBed` - the test will never complain about this: `NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!`.

So, we can propose, that `ElementRef` doesn't look like a dependency and always linked to the component itself. We're getting closer to the answer. :)

**Step 3**

Let's take a closer look on how `TestBed` creates component: `TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent)`. This is a very simplified version from the source code:

```
createComponent<T>(component: Type<T>): ComponentFixture<T> {
    this._initIfNeeded();
    const componentFactory = this._compiler.getComponentFactory(component);
    // ...
      const componentRef =
          componentFactory.create(Injector.NULL, [], `#${rootElId}`, this._moduleRef);
      return new ComponentFixture<T>(componentRef, ngZone, autoDetect);
    // ...
  }
```

So, we have to go forward and check the implementation of `ComponentFixture` class in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts):

```
export class ComponentFixture<T> {
  // The DebugElement associated with the root element of this component.
  debugElement: DebugElement;

  // The instance of the root component class.
  componentInstance: T;

  // The native element at the root of the component.
  nativeElement: any;

  // The ElementRef for the element at the root of the component.
  elementRef: ElementRef;

  // ...
  constructor(
      public componentRef: ComponentRef<T>, public ngZone: NgZone|null,
      private _autoDetect: boolean) {
    this.changeDetectorRef = componentRef.changeDetectorRef;
    this.elementRef = componentRef.location;
    // ...
```

We can see, that `elementRef` is a property of `ComponentFixture` class which is initialized the constructor.

And finally, summarizing the above - we've got the answer: `ElementRef` which is injected to the component in the constructor is actually a wrapper around the DOM element. The injected instance of `ElementRef` is a reference to the host element of the current component. Follow this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785118/difference-between-renderer-and-elementref-in-angular-2) to get more information about it.

This is why in the component constructor console.log we see the instance of `ElementRef` and not the instance of `MockElementRef`. So, what we actually provided in the TestBed providers array - is just another instance of `ElementRef` based on `MockElementRef`.

Comment: This is a long and detailed answer, but what about the bottom line. 
- What is the solution
- And if it cannot be done, you can write that it cannot be done.

Comment: I am also interested in this - how is one supposed to unit test the behavior of a component or a directive without the possibility of tampering with the elementRef?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is using `@ngneat/spectator` in Angular env. The ELementRef can be accessed by using:

```
const elementRef = new Spectator().debugElement;
```